# WizardNavigationEventArgs.Cancel = true not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, wizard

I have a Wizard on a web forms page with a function tied to its SideBarButtonClick event as follows:

```
protected void CreditWizard_SideBarButtonClick(object sender, 
                                               WizardNavigationEventArgs e)     
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    return;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to prevent the wizard from advancing to the step that gets clicked on. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: This is a 3 step wizard. If I click from the step 1 to step 3 via the sidebar buttons, I want to do some server sided validation on step 2 and if the validation fails to move them to the 2nd step instead. I figured the first step to this would be to cancel their navigation to the 3rd step, then move them to the 2nd, but `e.Cancel = true;` doesn't seem to stop their navigation to any steps.

Comment: Is this the finish step in your wizard or no?

Comment: It's not. I'll edit for more details.